# Generate static picture gallery website with image captions from EXIF tags

Tags: web-development, image-processing, static-site-generator

I am looking for a (command line) tool (preferably in Python) which generates a static picture gallery website from a folder of images.

The generated webpage should show along the photo **the caption and description from the EXIF tags** of the image. I assume the tool of choice would have output templates which can show caption and description of photos.

Additionally it would be great if the tool had a web theme with so called "responsive design", so that the generated web pages work well on smart phones, too.

First I found [Sigal](http://sigal.saimon.org/en/latest/), but it doesn't do captions with the standard themes. Then I came across [Nikola galleries](http://getnikola.com/galleries/demo/) and [Pelican-gallery plugin](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/gallery), but I don't know whether they show the EXIF captions - and how well they perform.

So advice *on these or other tools* to achieve what I want is much appreciated!

Comment: You could always use ImageMagik to automatically add captions to copies of the pictures.

Comment: @SteveBarnes How I understand the question, he already have the captions in the EXIF tags, and need show them in the html page...

Comment: @jm666 ImageMagik can also extract the EXIF tags.

Comment: From the docs of Sigal: _Sigal comes with two themes, based on the colorbox and galleria Javascript libraries._ The [galleria demo](http://saimon.org/sigal-demo/galleria/) is responsive - try resize your browser.

Comment: @jm666 Main requirement is to show the image captions from EXIF tags, the galleria demo doesn't display captions.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Interesting idea to "paint" text into the pictures, but it would certainly require quite a bit of additional coding which is not very maintainable...

Comment: @waldalla with a little experimentation you can have a one line batch/script file called PublishPict that will take a picture file or directory as a source and use ImageMagik to resize, add caption from specific EXIF field(s), output to the site specific location - just use that to get each picture ready to publish - very little maintenance just a process.

Comment: @SteveBarnes In regards to the maintenance aspect I have to disagree, because adding captions as glyphs to a picture is a maintenance nightmare: What e.g. when you want to change the theme of the site?

Comment: Nothing - unless you wish to change the captions based on the theme - given they are in the EXIFs that is unlikely!

Comment: Making Nikola show EXIF captions with the images is pretty easy. If you file a bug I can either do it or help you do it if you want to try yourself :-)

Answer (score 2):

From the Python wiki [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/StaticSiteGenerator) is a list of static site generators, since they are all Python based they should be scriptable and you can extract the Exif data using ImageMagick or the Python [ExifRead](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead) library:

- [Blogofile](http://www.blogofile.com/) - (Mako, Jinja2)-based generator with supports for (reStructuredText, Markdown, Textile), Git, Disqus, RSS feeds, plugins, and S3, very nice license with human touch.
- [Clay](http://lucuma.github.io/Clay/) - Jinja2 for easy site prototyping, MIT.
- [Complexity](http://complexity.rtfd.org/) - A refreshingly simple static site generator, for those who like to work in HTML.
- [Crotal](http://crotal.org/) - (Jinja2)-A static site generator written in Python, using Jinja2 template engine, BSD
- [Cyrax](https://github.com/piranha/cyrax) - poetic Jinja2 engine, used for osgameclones.
- [Hyde](http://hyde.github.com/) - Jinja2-based static web site generator, MIT, source
- [Mynt](http://mynt.mirroredwhite.com/) - Static website generator based on Markdown and Jinja2. BSD-3.
- [Nikola](http://getnikola.com/) - Generator supporting reST, Markdown, IPyNB et al.; using Mako and Jinja2 for templates; supports multilingual sites, galleries, RSS feeds, DISQUS et al. for comments. Incremental builds. MIT license.
- [Obraz](http://obraz.pirx.ru/) - Static blog-aware site generator mostly compatible with Jekyll, MIT
- [Poole](https://bitbucket.org/obensonne/poole) - static website generator, Markdown. GPL.
- [Pelican](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/) - Uses Markdown or ReST for content and Jinja 2 for themes. Supports DVCS, Disqus. AGPL.
- [PubTal](http://www.owlfish.com/software/PubTal/) - Templating#SimpleTAL-based static site generator, BSD-3
- [rest2web](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/rest2web/) - Generates Websites from ReST contents, BSD
- [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/index.html) - Python's official documentation system that turns ReST into HTML, LaTeX, man pages, plaintext, and has many features for making site trees, inter-linking, and other documentation necessities (Jinja2 as default template engine). BSD.
- [staticninja](https://github.com/Ceasar/staticjinja) - MIT, Jinja2, auto-compile. That simple.
- [tahchee](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Tahchee/1.0.0) - Cheetah-based static web site generator
- [Tinkerer](https://bitbucket.org/vladris/tinkerer/overview) - blogging engine/static website generator powered by Sphinx with polite-correct license list.
- [Urubu](http://urubu.jandecaluwe.com/) - A micro CMS for static websites, with a focus on good navigation practices. AGPL.
- [wok](http://wok.mythmon.com/) - MIT licensed, Jinja2, Markdown, reST, etc.

Comment: I am not interested in a general list of static site generators - rather a tool which creates picture galleries *with image captions*. I guess I am looking for something where the **templates** have the capability to show the captions...Will clarify this in the question!

Comment: @waldalla - any of those listed can with do that with minimal scripting - the unusual bit of your request is for the captions to be generated/extracted from the EXIF rather than being input into a text file.

Comment: Advice on details of the scripting would be much appreciated...

Comment: I don't see the point of such an answer. Given that there exist picture gallery generators that can be adjusted to show caption from EXIF tags, what is the point of mentioning many generic site generators that don't handle photo-specific stuff and thus would need much higher work to even come close to photo-specific generators?

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon The point is the flexibility gained by using such generators and the fact that they can be used to generate a site which contains such a gallery but in not necessarily restricted to such a gallery. Yes more work than dedicated gallery generators but also more benefit.

Comment: @waldalla: I would suggest something along the lines of using os.walk and one of the python exif packages to extract the exif data from each image and put it into a rtf file template plus create a thumbnail (Pillow) and add it with a short description to an index page for that directory. If each directory had a summary text/rtf file these and a random or specified thumbnail could be added to either a top level index or simply the level above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Python based. It is windows based but I used it in my business for years to generate various sized photos. The $15 program is called [Smaller Animals ThumnbNailer](http://www.smalleranimals.com/thumb.htm). It is command line, has a HTML templating system. Not sure on the exif part of your question though...

Comment: from destination link: _"Smaller Animals Software is out of business."_